# K8s deployment Minio How to access the Console?

Tags: kubernetes, minio

How do I access the Minio console?

`minio.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      name: minio
  selector:
    app: minio
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: minio
spec:
  serviceName: minio
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minio
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 20
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app
                  operator: In
                  values:
                    - minio
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
      - name: minio
        env:
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
          value: "hengshi"
        - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
          value: "hengshi202020"
        image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2018-08-02T23-11-36Z
        args:
        - server
        - http://minio-0.minio-internal.cts-cernerdevtools-minio.svc.cluster.local/data/
        - http://minio-1.minio-internal.cts-cernerdevtools-minio.svc.cluster.local/data/
        - http://minio-2.minio-internal.cts-cernerdevtools-minio.svc.cluster.local/data/
        - http://minio-3.minio-internal.cts-cernerdevtools-minio.svc.cluster.local/data/
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        - containerPort: 9001
        volumeMounts:
        - name: minio-data
          mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: minio-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 300M
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: server-port
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30009
    - name: console-port
      port: 9001
      targetPort: 9001
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30010
  selector:
    app: minio
```

`curl http://NodeIP:30010` is failed
I tried `container --args --console-address ":9001"`  or  `env  MINIO_BROWSER`   still not accessible

One more question, what is the latest image startup parameter for Minio? There seems to be something wrong with my args

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgXIa.png)

Comment: Please consider using the MinIO Operator where much of this setup is handled for you. The readme goes over the simple steps to get you going - https://github.com/minio/operator#procedure

Answer (score 4):

You can specify --console-address :9001 in your deployment.yaml file as below in args: section .

```
args:
  - server
  - --console-address
  - :9001
  - /data
```

Same way your Service and Ingress needs to point to 9001 port now with the latest Minio.

```
ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9001
```